# ERROR: Unable to start Group Replication 3096 (HY000) Can't add nodes to cluster INNODB

Tags: mysql, nodes, cluster-computing, innodb

Setup:

[All machines (4) are connected on LAN, updated, upgraded and they see themselves and work fine.]

I've installed mysql in all 4, I created a cluster but when I tried to add some nodes I get this error all the time, I've been researching for days and I cant find what's the issue.

[image: error while trying to add nodes to cluster]

Expected result: Nodes added succesfully and showing when status issued.

Cheers.

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: are you able to telnet these nodes from each other machines?

Answer (score 0):

While this may have been late, I am able to resolve the same issue by making sure that the /etc/hosts file are properly set on both primary and the host being added.